# Kiel oni fariĝas prezidanto de UEA?

Tags: uea

Mi scivolas kio estas la procedo por fariĝi prezidanto de UEA? Ĉu estas voĉdono de la membraro aŭ ĉu la estraro mem elektas rin? Aŭ alie? Kiuj estas la kriterioj por esti prezidanto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ĉi tiu artikolo](https://revuoesperanto.org/nova_prezidanto) havas interesan diskuton pri la bezonataj kriterioj por esti prezidanto.

La komitato elektas la estraron, inkluzive la prezidanton, ĉiujn 3 jarojn. Ĉiuj estraranoj, inkluzive la prezidanton, devas esti komitatano. Por esti komitatano, unue oni devas esti individua membro de UEA dum almenaŭ 2 jaroj antaŭ la elektiĝo.

Estas tri tipoj de komitatanoj:

- komitatanoj A, elektitaj de la aliĝintaj asocioj, de la observantoj kaj de la junulara sekcio;
- komitatanoj B, elektitaj de la individuaj membroj;
- komitatanoj C, elektitaj de la komitatanoj A kaj B.

Do oni devas elektiĝi kiel unu el tiuj 3 tipoj. Sekve por fariĝi estrarano, du aliaj komitatanoj devas proponi onin kaj oni devas gajni voĉdonon.

La artikolo ankaŭ mencias aliajn kondiĉojn por prezidanteco:

- Strategia aliro
- Elstaraj publikparolaj kapabloj
- Diplomatia kaj reprezenta personeco
- Sperto en gvidado de volontula organizo
- Sperto en la Esperanto-movado
- Sperto en konfliktsolvado
- Laboremo
- Fleksebleco
- Scipovo de Esperanto je almenaŭ C1-nivelo.